# html_table isn't recognising my node pass despite it being a table

Tags: r, rvest

New to the `rvest` package.. I'm trying to extract the table seen here, which comprises of results from an athletics event.

https://www.decathlon2000.com/720/gotzis-2000/

Rudimentary `rvest` utilisation seems to be passing the url to `read_html`, then selecting the relevant css selectors using the "Selectorgadget" js bookmarklet, then inserting this in to `html_nodes`, which I've done.

```
gotzis2000 <- read_html("https://www.decathlon2000.com/720/gotzis-2000/")

gotzis2000 %>% html_nodes("#articlecontent td")
```

However, when I try and then pipe this into `html_table`:

`gotzis2000 %>% html_nodes("#articlecontent td") %>% html_table()`

I get the error `Error: html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE`.

When I pipe the above with `html_text`, I can see the data has been extracted, so I'm not sure what the correct procedures are from here.

Comment: `<td>` is a table cell, so it won't contain a table. You need to select an actual table element--first `html_nodes("#articlecontent")` then `html_node("table")` will get you a table element

Comment: you should make that an answer. totally solves the problem.